# node.js eventemitter create multiple objects or rely on arguments?

Tags: javascript, events, node.js, eventemitter

Asking about eventemitters in node.js

For different events, should I create new emitters on a base object:

```
forum.closeThread = new ee()
forum.openThread = new ee()
forum.openThread.on(threadID, foo)
```

or rely on arguments to trigger

```
forum.events.on('openThread', foo)
forum.events.on('closeThread', bar)
var bar = function (threadID) {...}
```

What is recommended?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the latter more readable

```
forum.on('thread-open', threadID, foo)
forum.on('thread-close', threadID, bar)
```

I would make `forum` extend `EventEmitter` myself.

```
var Forum = function() {
    ...
}

Forum.prototype = new events.EventEmitter;

var forum = new Forum();
```

Comment: how do I use forum to extend EventEmitter? Could you give me a quick code sample. Thanks